# Linear Algebra /Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^9$ such that $V \nsubseteq W$ and $V+W \neq \mathbb{R}^9$.If $\dim V =3, \; \dim W=7$ , then calculate $\dim V \cap W$.

*Well , this is probably considered to be an easy problem, but I cannot go around it. I know I have to use the dimensional equation $\dim (V+W) =\dim V + \dim W - \dim V\cap W$, but I cannot combine the other data to extract the dimension of the intersection. From the data $V+W\neq \mathbb{R}^9$ I extract that $\dim (V+W)\neq 9$, hence $\dim (V+W) \leq 8$. Since $\dim W =7$ I said that $\dim (V+w)=8$ hence the dimension of the intersection is $2$. I have a feeling that my solution is not complete. Therefore I'dd like some hints.*

Comment: You need to say why $\dim (V + W) > 7$. Then it's complete.

Comment: Exactly that I cannot extract. I based that part on intuition. I have not used that $V \nsubseteq W$ at all.

Comment: Then using that seems to be a good idea. You have deduced $\dim (V+W) < 9$ from $V+W \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^9$. You deduce $\dim (V+W) > 7$ from $?? \subsetneq V+W$.

Comment: Well $W \subsetneq V+W $ . So the proof is complete, no? I hope I have not made any mistakes here.

Comment: Yes. $W \subsetneq V+W \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^9 \implies \dim W < \dim (V+W) < \dim \mathbb{R}^9$ (since all dimensions are finite).

Comment: Thank you I shall write a complete proof now.. below, just for the question to have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. I would have approached it slightly differently as follows. You know that $\dim (V+W) =\dim V + \dim W - \dim(V\cap W)=10-\dim(V\cap W)$. Now since $V\not\subseteq W$ you know that $\dim(V\cap W)<\dim V=3$. So $\dim(V+W)$ is obtained by subtracting less than $3$ from$~10$, so it is at least$~8$. But $V+W\subsetneq\Bbb R^9$ means it must be$~8$ exactly, whence $\dim(V\cap W)=10-8=2$.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here is the complete proof of this answer based on the hint above.

We are using the dimensional equation:
$$\dim (V+W)=\dim V+ \dim W -\dim V\cap W$$

Since $V+W \neq \mathbb{R}^9$ that means that $\dim (V+W) <9$ .

From the data $V \nsubseteq W$ we get that $W \subsetneq W+ V \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^9$ hence $\dim W < \dim (W+V) <\dim \mathbb{R}^9$.(since all dimensions are finite)

However $\dim W =7$ hence $7<\dim (V+W)<9$ therefore $\dim (V+W)=8$ since the dimension is a natural number.

Hence:
$$\dim V \cap W=2$$

and the proof is complete.

Comment: Instead of $W \nsubseteq W+ V \nsubseteq \mathbb{R}^9$ you should say $W \subsetneq W+ V \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^9$, in other words they _are_ subsets but not equal (write `\subsetneq` instead of `\nsubseteq`).

Comment: Thank you.. Let me edit that.